# How to move dataset from Azure Managed Instance to Azure SQL using SSIS with change data capture

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, change-data-capture, azure-sql-managed-instance, azure-managed-database

How to move data from Azure Managed Instance to Azure SQL Database by using SSIS package with Change data capture feature in it?
Please help me with links or documents.

Comment: There is no CDC in Azure SQL Database yet. If possible, could you please let me know more about the use case. If the object is just to move the data, you can use other tools. Any specific reason to use CDC, SSIS?

Answer (score 0):

Good news, CDC was implemented for Managed Instance and Azure SQL Database as per [yesterday](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-sql/track-and-record-data-changes-with-change-data-capture-cdc-in/ba-p/2504205):

*"Change data capture (CDC) records insert, update, and delete activity that applies to tables in SQL Server, Azure SQL Managed Instance or Azure SQL Databases [...]"*

You can see some common scenarios in [this video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Data-Exposed/Track-and-Record-Data-Changes-with-Change-Data-Capture-CDC-in-Azure-SQL).